# how to show selected data in checkbox with many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get data from `tbl_user_group` on basis of the user_id that to how many groups a user belong

when I use this piece of code in my view i go this

code:

```
 <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selected Groups <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">         
         <?php $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_user_group')->where('user_id', $editUser->user_id)->get()->result(); ?>

          <?php foreach ($query as $value) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($getTblUserGroup as $group) : ?>
                      <div class="c-checkbox needsclick">
                          <?php if ($group->id == $value->gropup_id) : ?>
                          <label class="needsclick">
                          <input type="checkbox"  checked="<?php $group->id == $value->gropup_id ? 'check' : '' ?>" value="<?php $group->id ?>" name="gropup_id[]" class="needsclick">
                          <strong class="badge btn-primary"><?= $group->group_name ?></strong>  
                          </label>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                      </div>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>                                    
              <?php endforeach; ?>

              </div>
```

result;

[image]

when i try this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">         
    <?php $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_user_group')->where('user_id', $editUser->user_id)->get()->result(); ?>

          <?php foreach ($query as $value) : ?>
              <?php foreach ($getTblUserGroup as $group) : ?>
                  <div class="c-checkbox needsclick">
                       <?php if ($group->id == $value->gropup_id) : ?>
                          <label class="needsclick">
                          <input type="checkbox"  checked="check" value="<?php $group->id ?>" name="gropup_id[]" class="needsclick">
                          <strong class="badge btn-primary"><?= $group->group_name ?></strong>  
                          </label>
                          <?php else : ?>
                          <label class="needsclick">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="<?php $group->id ?>" name="gropup_id[]" class="needsclick">
                          <strong class="badge btn-primary"><?= $group->group_name ?></strong>  
                          </label>    
                     <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>    
          <?php endforeach; ?>    
      </div>
```

result is this
[image]

how can i get the groups in which user belong is checked and other unchecked but in my case i m getting only checked or repetition of groups which are unassigned.

Comment: <?php $group->id ?> should be <?php echo $group->id ?> I think?? Queries in the view ... why use framework?

Comment: i write query in the view just for myself i'll remove it later but i think u didn't read my question it not the echo problem data is showing in in repetition

Comment: At least come with working code examples if you want people to understand your code.